# OSB 12c IDE alternative to jdeveloper

Tags: ide, oracle12c, jdeveloper, osb

Someone knows of an IDE alternative to jdeveloper to develop OSB 12c.
I am using jdeveloper, but it has many problems with reference and integration with the server, it is a very unstable IDE.
I will be very argade if you know an alternative, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDeveloper is the only IDE you can use with OSB 12c. Support for Eclipse does not exist anymore.

Check out more here: http://munzandmore.com/tag/osb-12c